# why cant we use a reference variable of super class to access methods of its subclass(methods not available in super class)?

Tags: java, polymorphism, run-time-polymorphism

I know that,No matter what the actual object is,that the reference variable refers to,The methods i can call on a reference is dependent on the declared type of the variable (in line 15 of code).I want to know why so.Why can't the class user use the reference variable s of type Shape to call its subclass method drawCircle()?

```
    public class Shape{
            public void displayShape(){
               System.out.println("shape displayed");
                      }
    public class Circle extends Shape{
            public void drawCircle(){
                System.out.println("circle drawn");
                      }
    public class Test{
            p.s.v.main(String[] a){
            Circle c=new Circle();
            Shape s=new Shape();
            display(c);
            display(s);
            public void display(Shape myShape){
               myShape.displayShape();//possible for ref variable c and s
               myShape.drawCircle();//not possible for reference var s
               }
             }
         }
```

Can u provide me an explanation of what happens at the object level?I am new to java.

Comment: correct your code and write full codes don`t use shortcuts like you have used here "p.s.v" instead write public static void main(String args[]). Plus there are many more mistakes, so kindly refactor your code once.Nested functions are not allowed in java if you want to  achieve such functionality use lambda expressions of java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler just knows that `myShape` is a reference variable of type `Shape`, which contains only one method `displayShape()` , so according to the compiler, it is not possible to call a method `drawCircle()` which the `Shape` class does not contain.

The compiler is not concerned with what object this variable will hold at runtime. You may extend another class from the `Shape` class at some later point of time, and use the `myShape` reference to hold that subclass object. The compiler is just concerned with what type `myShape` is at compile-time.

If your `Circle` class happened to override the `displayShape()` method, like below :

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
    public void displayShape() {
        System.out.println("I am a Circle!");
    }

    public void drawCircle() {
    // Implementation here
    }
}
```

the only decision happening at runtime would be which `displayShape()` method to call.

Answer (score 0):

First, you forgot to make `Circle` subclass of `Shape`.

Then you said :

> The methods i can call on a reference is dependent on the declared
>   type of the variable

But the `Shape myShape` parameter is also a variable :

```
 public void display(Shape myShape){
    ...
    myShape.drawCircle();
 }
```

So also here, as for a local variable or a field variable, the compiler relies only the declared type to bound the invoked method. 
And as the `Shape` class is used as the type of the declared variable, only methods of this class may be invoked on.

Comment: It's not even possible to call `display` method, its declared in main method body somehow, that seems to be his issue.

Comment: @user3734782 It is right. I don't think that it is its problem even it may be misleading. I think that it is just a very approximative and pseudo code. You have also             `p.s.v.main(String[] a){` and `display` should be static method. But well...

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that myShape is a Circle you can explicitly cast  it to one
`((Circle)myShape).drawCircle();` or `Circle myCircle = (Circle)myShape; myCircle.drawCircle();` but if you do that and it isn't actually a `Circle` then you will get a `ClassCastException`.

Generally, you want to try and avoid this sort of casting though as its something of a code smell which suggests your design is a bit off. (Sometimes you do need to do it, but its not taking advantage of polymorphism).

To take advantage of polymorphism you would instead have `Shape` define `displayShape()` as an abstract method and then instead of `drawCircle()`, `drawSquare()` etc... each subclass of `Shape` will have its own version of the `displayShape()` method, while in `Shape` itself you would have:
`public abstract displayShape();` which is a way of telling the compiler "all my subclasses will have this displayShape() method so when someone calls displayShape() on one of me, use the one defined in that subclass".

So for example:

```
Shape myCircle = new Circle();
Shape mySquare = new Square();
myCircle.displayShape(); //draws a circle
mySquare.displayShape(); //draws a square

//And if you can't choose which one you want...
Shape surpriseMe = new Random().nextBoolean() ? myCircle : mySquare;
surpriseMe.displayShape(); //draws either a circle or a square!
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [reading about polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

```
public abstract class Shape {
   public abstract void draw();
}

public class Circle extends Shape {
    @Override
    public void draw() {
       System.out.println("Circle drawed");
    }
}

public class Triangle extends Shape {
    @Override
    public void draw() {
       System.out.println("Triangle drawed");
    }
}

public class Test() {
   public static void display(Shape shape) {
      shape.draw();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //how can you define "shape" in real world? its triangle or... -> abstraction
      Circle c = new Circle();
      Triangle t = new Triangle();

      display(c);
      display(t);
   } 
}
```